# javascript add two textbox values and display in third in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How do I in javascript/asp add two textbox values and display in third?

My JS code

```
 function sum() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
          document.getElementById('TextBox3').value = result;
      }
  }
```

ASP in page load

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "sum();");
TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "sum();");
```

Comment: Using `ClientID` like `var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value` should work for ASPX webforms page (if you're not setting `ClientIDMode="Static"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should know:

By default, ASP.NET uses auto-generated `ClientID` property to be used by `TextBox` control in ASPX pages, so that your textbox ID will become something like `<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1" type="text" ... />` after rendered. To use the server control name in client-side you need to use `ClientID` like this:

```
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>').value;
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>').value = result;
    }
}
```

An alternative to avoid using generated `ClientID` in client-side is setting `ClientIDMode` to be static, here are examples to use it:

```
<%-- control level --%>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ... />

<%-- placeholder level --%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ...>...</asp:Content>

<%-- page level --%>
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>
```

Reference:

[ClientID Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in `aspx` without using code behind.

```
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" cssclass="sum" runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="TextBox2" cssclass="sum" runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="txtResult" runat="server" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //this calculates values automatically 
        calculateSum();

        $(".sum").on("keydown keyup", function () {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".sum").each(function () {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });

        $("#<%=this.txtResult.ClientID%>").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```